# Find the set of values of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the function $f(x) = xe^{\frac{a}{x}}$ has $2$ asimptotes.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I am given the function:

$$f:(0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{2cm} f(x) = xe^{\frac{a}{x}}$$

with $a \in \mathbb{R}$. I have to find the set of values of $a$ for which the function $f(x)$ has $2$ asymptotes. Through a bit of calculation, I have found that the line:

$$y = x + a$$

is the slant asymptote as $x \to \infty$, for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. So far, we have $1$ asymptote.

Now, the only way for us to have $2$ asymptotes for this function is for the function to have a vertical asymptote at $x = 0$. So I have to find the values of $a$ for which we have:

$$\lim_{x \to +0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to +0} xe^{\frac{a}{x}} = +\infty$$

or

$$\lim_{x \to +0} f(x) = \lim_{x \to +0} xe^{\frac{a}{x}} = -\infty$$

How can I do this? What are the values of $a$ for which the function goes to $\pm \infty$ as $x \to +0$?

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that if $a=0$ then $\exp(a/x) = 1$ for all $x>0$ and hence $f(x) = x$.
Of course, this fails our requirements.

Now, if $a<0$, then $a/x\to-\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$ and hence $\exp(a/x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$. Clearly, this implies that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = 0$.

---

Finally, for $a>0$, remember that

$$\exp(t) = \sum_{k\geqslant 0} \frac{t^k}{k!}.$$

$t = a/x >0$, so all summands are positive and truncating at $k=2$ is enough for us.
We have

$$f(x) = x\exp(a/x) \geqslant x\left(1 + \frac ax +\frac{a^2}{2x^2}\right) = x + a + \frac{a^2}{2x}.$$

As $x\to0^+$ the RHS goes to $+\infty$, and thus so too does $f(x)$.

Comment: Can you please link me to a source where you got that definition of $\exp(t)$? I've never seen it before.

Comment: Have you heard of power series before?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Sorry.

Comment: What is the definition of exponential you are used to? [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) is the usual definition, although there are others.

Comment: Moreover, what techniques for finding indeterminate limits do you know of? L'Hopital?